# Creating a class that inherits SerialPort

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, instance, instantiation

I have a class that inherits `SerialPort` and this class sets properties of a serial port as shown in the code below.

```
Public Class Ports
    Inherits SerialPort

    WithEvents port As New SerialPort()
    Sub New()
        With port
            .BaudRate = 19200
            .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            .RtsEnable = False
            .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
            .NewLine = vbCr
            .ReadTimeout = 10000
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

The issue with this is when I instantiate it,

```
Private WithEvents testPort As New Ports()
```

the properties of the `SerialPort` aren't transferred over and the default values are set.

Comment: Creating a SerialPort inside your class that inherits from SerialPort is weird. Your value are not set inside the instance for inside instance.port. I would remove the port variable, or remove the inheritance.

Comment: The reason I'm doing the inheritance is because I need all of the other methods in the serial port class.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand what you're saying.

Comment: When you do "Dim p As New Ports", the value you set won't be in p.BaudRate but in p.port.BaudRate. You have decide; if p.BaudRate is needed then delete p.port. If p.port.BaudRate is needed, then remove the inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your not setting the instance for the object rather you are doing it for another variable inside that instance. As @the_lotus pointed out, remove the variable or the inheritance. I would recommend just removing the non needed variable `WithEvents port As New SerialPort()` and then use the instance...

```
Public Class Ports
    Inherits SerialPort

    Sub New()
        With Me
            .BaudRate = 19200
            .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            .RtsEnable = False
            .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
            .NewLine = vbCr
            .ReadTimeout = 10000
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Oh! I understand now. Wow, I need a refresher on instantiation.

Comment: @HighMans it's ok we all have those moments. Glad I could help!